# 'clearfix' in Redmine wiki

Tags: wiki, redmine

Is there a way to insert a floating image to Redmine wiki-page and apply something like 'clear:both' to following header or at least to native Redmine's controls (such as 'attach file' and 'export to pdf|html|text')?

Answer (score 1):

With my theme ([A1](http://redminecrm.com/pages/a1-theme)) the following snippet did the job:

```
h2. A header

p(clear). !{width:50%;float:left}image1.jpg! !{width:50%;float:left}image2.jpg!

h2. Next header
```